# Find the limit of the function without L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have a problem, such as:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{\cos(ax)}{\cos(bx)}\right)^\frac{1}{x^2}$$

How do I solve this problem without using L'Hôpital's rule or small-o?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Basically a variant of user's answer: Using familiar limits $(1-u)^{1/u}\to e^{-1}$ and ${\sin u\over u}\to1$ as $u\to0$, we have

$$\begin{align}
(\cos ax)^{1/x^2}
&=(\cos^2ax)^{1/(2x^2)}\\
&=(1-\sin^2ax)^{1/(2x^2)}\\
&=\left((1-\sin^2ax)^{1/\sin^2ax}\right)^{(a^2/2)(\sin ax/(ax))^2}\\
&\to (e^{-1})^{(a^2/2)\cdot1^2}\\
&=e^{-a^2/2}
\end{align}$$

So in general we have

$$\left(\cos ax\over\cos bx\right)^{1/x^2}={(\cos ax)^{1/x^2}\over(\cos bx)^{1/x^2}}\to{e^{-a^2/2}\over e^{-b^2/2}}=e^{(b^2-a^2)/2}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, is it possible to give more details about this transformation? How did you get: (a^2 / 2)(sin ax / (ax))^2. I understand that in order to keep the function the same you took: (1/sin^2 ax)(sin^2ax / 2x^2) out of brackets, but how did you transformed it?

Comment: @Grimmie, it may help if you see the exponenets in built-up fraction form:  $${1\over2x^2}={1\over\sin^2ax}\cdot{a^2\over2}\left(\sin ax\over ax\right)^2$$ Basically the sines and the $a^2$s on the right hand side cancel out. Let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: again thank you, do I understand correctly, (1/2x^2)/(1/sin^2ax) = (sin^2 ax / 2x^2) ; (a^2/2) (Sinx/x)^2?

Comment: @Grimmie, sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by the semicolon. It'll help if you put dollar signs around your math expressions, so that TeX will typeset them more clearly.

Comment: I meant new line.
$$(1/2x^2)/(1/sin^2ax) = (sin^2 ax / 2x^2)$$
$$(a^2/2) (Sinx/x)^2$$

Comment: $$(1/2x^2)/(1/sin^2ax) = (sin^2 ax / 2x^2) = (a^2/2) (Sinx/x)^2$$

Sorry I am trying to get hang of TeX

Comment: The first equality is correct, the second is not. It looks like you are saying $\sin ax=a\sin x$, and that's not right. If it's still unclear how I got from $1/(2x^2)$ to $(1/\sin^2ax)(a^2/2)(\sin ax/(ax))^2$, you might do well to ask that as a new question, with a link to here.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am trying to figure out, really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

We can use that

$$\left(\frac{\cos(ax)}{\cos(bx)}\right) ^\tfrac{1}{x^2}=\left(\frac{1-(1-\cos(ax))}{1-(1-\cos(bx))}\right) ^\tfrac{1}{x^2}$$

and then use that

$$1-(1-\cos(ax))^\tfrac{1}{x^2}=\left(1-(1-\cos(ax))^\tfrac1{1-\cos(ax)}\right)^{a^2\tfrac{1-\cos(ax)}{(ax)^2}}$$

$$1-(1-\cos(bx))^\tfrac{1}{x^2}=\left(1-(1-\cos(bx))^\tfrac1{1-\cos(bx)}\right)^{b^2\tfrac{1-\cos(bx)}{(bx)^2}}$$

and refer to standard limits.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of $t:=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\ln\cos y}{y^2}$, write your limit as $L=\exp\ell$ with$$\ell:=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln\tfrac{\cos ax}{\cos bx}}{x^2}=t(a^2-b^2).$$We now prove $t=-\tfrac12$ so $L=\exp\tfrac{b^2-a^2}{2}$. In terms of $z:=1-\cos y$,$$t=\underbrace{\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\ln(1-z)}{-z}}_{1}\underbrace{\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\cos y-1}{y^2}}_{-\tfrac12}.$$

Comment: So you mean that we are turning it to (1+1/x)^x = e form?

Comment: @Grimmie I don't see it that way, only that we're taking logarithms, then using two well-known limits.

Answer (score 1):

Composing Taylor series
$$y= \left(\frac{\cos(ax)}{\cos(bx)}\right)^\frac{1}{x^2}\implies\log(y)=\frac{1}{x^2}\big[\log(\cos(ax))-\log(\cos(bx))\big]$$

Using
$$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+O\left(x^6\right)$$
$$\cos(cx)=1-\frac{c^2 x^2}{2}+\frac{c^4 x^4}{24}+O\left(x^6\right)$$
$$\log(\cos(ax))=-\frac{c^2 x^2}{2}-\frac{c^4 x^4}{12}+O\left(x^6\right)$$

Use it twice (for $c=a$ and $c=b$ and subtract to get
$$\log(\cos(ax))-\log(\cos(bx))=\frac{1}{2} x^2 \left(b^2-a^2\right)+\frac{1}{12} x^4
   \left(b^4-a^4\right)+O\left(x^6\right)$$
$$\log(y)=\frac{1}{2} \left(b^2-a^2\right)+\frac{1}{12} x^2
   \left(b^4-a^4\right)+O\left(x^4\right)$$
$$y=e^{\log(y)}=e^{\frac {b^2-a^2}2}\left(1+\frac{1}{12} x^2 \left(b^4-a^4\right)+O\left(x^4\right)\right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\cos(ax)^{1/x^2}=\lim_{t\to0}\cos(t)^{a^2/t^2}=\lim_{t\to0}(\cos(t)^{1/t^2})^{a^2}=\left(\lim_{t\to0}(\cos(t)^{1/t^2}\right)^{a^2}$$ and the answer is of the form

$$c^{a^2-b^2}.$$

We can find $c$ with

$$(\cos(t))^{1/t^2}=\left(\left(1-2\sin^2\left(\frac t2\right)\right)^{1/\sin^2(\frac t2)}\right)^{\sin^2(\frac t2)/4(\frac t2)^2}\to (e^{-2})^{1/4}.$$